# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when opening modal in Angular

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

```
`<ngx-datatable-column *ngIf="search_type ==='booking'" [width]="50" [sortable]="false"
                  [canAutoResize]="false" [draggable]="false" [resizeable]="false">

                  <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row" let-value="value">
                    <span class="fa fa-user-plus font-medium-3 text-primary cursor-pointer pl-1"
                      (click)="onUpdateBookingLinguist(row)"></span>
                  </ng-template>
                </ngx-datatable-column>`
```

Above is my html code and below is my ts code

```
`  onUpdateBookingLinguist(linguist: Linguist) {

    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ScheduledBookingModalComponent, { size: 'lg' });
    modalRef.componentInstance.linguist_other_bookings = linguist['scheduled_booking'];

    modalRef.result.then((result) => {

      if (!result) {
        return;
      }

      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }).catch((e) => { });

    this.cdr.detectChanges();

  }`
```

I am trying to open the modal from ngx-datatable-column but getting this error

ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'datatable-body-cell sort-active active'. Current value: 'datatable-body-cell sort-active'.. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

I have tried manually triggering change detection using ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() but still getting the error.

Comment: do manual change detection inside `ngAfterContentInit` lifecycle.

Comment: I already tried this and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by changing span into the button and now it's working fine.

```
<ngx-datatable-column *ngIf="search_type ==='booking'" [width]="50" [sortable]="false"
              [canAutoResize]="false" [draggable]="false" [resizeable]="false">

              <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row" let-value="value">
                <button (click)="onUpdateBookingLinguist(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-for-add-linguist font-medium-3"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></button>
              </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error often arises when you're modifying a property that Angular is also trying to check or update during its change detection cycle.

So, you can use `ChangeDetectorRef` to manually trigger change detection in specific cases.

Here's an example of how you can use `ChangeDetectorRef` in your component:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngAfterContentInit() {

   this.cdr.detectChanges();

}
```